# where to initialize the ID from GCM?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I use GCM in my project.Where do I get an ID, so it is always available at all times? Here is my code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (!CloudMessaging.checkPlayServices(this)) {
            return;
        }
        CloudMessaging.getInstance(this).setRegistrationListener(eventHandler);
    }
```

"but if I turn aside and then expand Programmes at, then again will get ID." ->Possibly: 
If I change my orientation, then again I get a new Id.

Comment: another important issue. who can say with confidence - ID, change or always the same?

Comment: You need to store your id on a SharedPreference whenever you get a id. When the id is changed, you need to replace the old id on the SharedPreference with a new one.

Comment: I'm doing. and it turns out that I have on every  receive ID, and compare with the ID, from SharedPreference

Comment: Also, you should only change your registration ID (or call `gcm.register()` again), when you do app updates and backups/restores. Refer [here](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html#reg-state).

Answer (score 0):

You can get your ID for GCM

```
if (m_gcm == null)
{
        m_gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(m_context);
}
m_regid = m_gcm.register("Your project id from google api console");
```

**Note** : please do this network operation in background thread..

Answer (score 0):

Use `SharedPreferences` to store your ID once you get a new one.

**Steps required:** (do this in your onCreate)

- Check if you already have a valid GCM id in your `SharedPreferences`
- If you already have one, use it.
- Otherwise, request a new one and save it in your `SharedPreferences`.